# How to create Objects in database if does not exists with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, persistence

I have a web application that I use JPA / Hibernate I want to know how to hibernate can generate the  non-existent tables from entities.
the persistence file is as follows:

What I can add as property ?

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="BankingApp">
        <provider> org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question.  How can a table be generated from a non-existent entity? Do you want it to generate every possible table?

Comment: @JohnAment    No, I want the table to be generated from the entity

Comment: are you asking how does hibernate generate the tables if no instances of a class exits? or if no class definition (with entity annotation/mapping) exists?

Comment: @user2264997 I want to create the entities classes and tables will be generated after build. ie generate table form entity

Comment: by default, hibernate can do this on deployment, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto with values, create, update etc.  this will automatically apply to the connection.  hibernate tools supports this to output to a file as well, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/toolsetguide.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add this property

```xml
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

The possible values for this property are:

- validate: Only validates the schema
- update: Update the schema
- create: Create the schema, override previous data
- create-drop: Create the schema and drop the schema at the end of the session

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, simply add the following property:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```