# Table creation via JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have an entity class as `ClassA` which contains

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
List<ClassB> possibleValues;
```

This statement will enter values in table `classa` and there in it also enters values in `classb` respective to `ClassA`.

Does it create any table like `classa_possible_values` and enter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set which entity is the owner of the relationship using annotations and set how the data is stored in the database.

For example, you can set a foreign key in the ClassB table to ClassA. The list of ClassB in the entity ClassA don't have any column in the ClassA table, but the list is persisted as foreign keys in ClassB. To implement this, you need to add a mappedBy value in the 'OneToMany' annotation and add a 'ManyToOne' annotation in ClassB:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy=classA)
List<ClassB> possibleValues;
```

In classB:

```
@Entity
public ClassB {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    ClassA classA;
    ...
}
```

There are other options, like creating a joinTable for the relationship, but in my opinion this is the more simple solution.

If you want to generate the database schema based on the JPA annotations, you need to add some properties to your configuration, for example, this is how to add this configuration for JPA/Hibernate: [Hibernate schema generation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712220/how-to-create-objects-in-database-if-does-not-exists-with-jpa/17719158#17719158)

Comment: Ok what is happening in my current situation is ClaasA values are persisted to table classa, ClassB values are respective to ClassA are persisted to classb and a mapping table mapping to both the primary id has been generated.ClassB does not contain `@ManyToOne`.Do you have any idea for this config?Shall I create `@ManyToOne` for classA as you suggested?

Comment: If you don't set the 'ManyToOne' annotation, a join table is created. You can't store multiple ClassB foreign keys in a ClassA  table row. If the 'ManyToOne' annotation is set in ClassB, the ClassA foreign keys can be stored in ClassB table and the join table is not needed.

Comment: Thanks :) Can you plz refer me some tutorial from where I can clear the concepts?

Comment: You should be able to find some good JPA tutorials, anyways this is a short tutorial about this topic: [Understanding JPA, Part 2: Relationships the JPA way](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html). If you want to spend some time learning JPA, I strongly suggest this book: `PRO JPA2 Mastering the Java Persistence API`

Comment: ya! I knew the link but not the detailed lessons.Thanks for suggesting book and giving time :)

Answer (score 0):

There would be no tables generated from this annotation, these merely define relationships between tables. If you add a `@JoinColumn` annotation, then a foreign key *column* would be generated by your JPA provider.

Comment: JPA does not creates entries by itself. Only if you persist entries.